# Why my ListView with CheckBox id getting confused?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-checkbox

I'm implementing a ListView with checkbox in witch cell. But the problem is when I check in one cell and roll down the list, it get confused and others cells get checked too. Do I havo to do something else in my getView method?

This is my CustonAdapter:

```
public class AcessoriosItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<AcessoriosItensLista> listAcessorios = new ArrayList<AcessoriosItensLista>();
Context context;    

public AcessoriosItemAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listAcessorios.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listAcessorios.get(index);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return index;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_acessorios, parent, false);             
    }       

    AcessoriosItensLista acessorios = (AcessoriosItensLista)getItem(index);

    ImageView imgAcessorio = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgAcessorioLista);

    String nomeImagem = acessorios.getNomeImagens();
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nomeImagem, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    imgAcessorio.setBackgroundResource(id); 

    TextView tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeAcessoriosLinha);
    tvNome.setText(acessorios.getNomeAcessorio());      

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cbListaAcessorios);


    return view;
}   


public void addDadosAcessorios(String nomeAcessorio, String nomeImagens, boolean checked) {

    listAcessorios.add(new AcessoriosItensLista(nomeAcessorio, nomeImagens, checked));

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is because `listview` recycles the list item views. Since you do not reset the checked state in the `getView()` the state is maintained when you scroll and items gets recycled.

What is needed is a way to keep track of the state of each checkbox based on its position. So you could confidently tell: checkbox at position `k` is checked or not!

You need to keep track of the checkboxes which have been clicked so that when `getView()` is called, you can update the state of the `checkbox`.

1) Maintain a `list` of checkbox positions which are checked.

2) If checkbox is clicked and checked, add its position to the `list`. If it is clicked again (unchecked), remove it from the list.

3) Use this `list` and update the checked state of the checkbox in the `getView()`

Code:

```
public class AcessoriosItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<AcessoriosItensLista> listAcessorios = new ArrayList<AcessoriosItensLista>(); 
    Context context;    

    // store a list of position where checbox is selected.
    ArrayList<Integer> checkedPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_acessorios, parent, false);             
        }       

        AcessoriosItensLista acessorios = (AcessoriosItensLista)getItem(index);

        ImageView imgAcessorio = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgAcessorioLista);

        String nomeImagem = acessorios.getNomeImagens();
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nomeImagem, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        imgAcessorio.setBackgroundResource(id); 

        TextView tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeAcessoriosLinha);
        tvNome.setText(acessorios.getNomeAcessorio());      

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cbListaAcessorios);
        final Integer position = new Integer(index);

        // when checkbox is clicked, we add/remove its position to/from the list
        cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    // if checked, we add it to the list
                    checkedPositions.add(position);
                }
                else if(checkedPositions.contains(position)) {
                    // else if remove it from the list (if it is present)
                    checkedPositions.remove(position);
                }

            }
        });
        // set the state of the checbox based on if it is checked or not.
        cb.setChecked(checkedPositions.contains(position));

        return view;
    }   

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old question, but I found an issue in the accepted answer while I used it. The line: checkedPositions.remove(position); does not delete the integer but the position in the list. Which is not what you want. You need something like this: int pos = checkedPositions.indexOf(position); checkedPositions.remove(pos);